# Can I install PostgreSql Version 8.4 and Version 9.0 on windows simultaneously

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, installation, postgresql

We have a windows test server for a software product we develop that has a number of different databases installed on it including PostgreSql 8.4.

We would like to install PostgreSql 9.0 on this server as well, while retaining the current 8.4 install - is this possible, and if so, how (it's a 64bit Windows Server 2008 r2 machine)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, just use different ports. The installer will handle this for you, don't worry.